# How to pass refs to a component in alpine js 3?

Tags: alpine.js

I created a component named `user` in alpine js and add an `init` function to it. Something like this

```
<div x-data="user()" x-init="init($refs)">
    <div x-ref="entry"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function user() {
        return {
            init: function($refs) {
                console.log('run')
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

But what is happening, is the `init` function is called two times. Then, I get to know that functions called init are auto invoked in Alpine v3 (https://alpinejs.dev/directives/init#auto-evaluate-init-method). If you add `x-init="init()"`, init will be called twice. So, I removed the `init()` from the HTML.

```
<div x-data="user()">
    <div x-ref="entry"></div>
</div>
```

and it works fine. But, now `$refs` gives an error saying

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'entry')`
How can i pass `$refs` to the `init()` function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here `user()` is an Alpine.js component that you can also create via [`Alpine.data()`](https://alpinejs.dev/globals/alpine-data) global method. Inside a component you can access each "magic" property like `$refs`, but you have to use the `this.` prefix:

```
<div x-data="user">
    <div x-ref="entry"></div>
</div>

<script>
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
    Alpine.data('user', () => ({
        init() {
           // Access "entry" ref
           console.log(this.$refs.entry)
        }
    }))
})
</script>
```